# Replicate rows by different N

Tags: r

I’ve the following data

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), n=c(2.63, 1.5, 0.5, 3.5, 4))
```

1)  I need to repeat number of rows for each id by n. For example, n=2.63 for id=1, then I need to replicated id=1 row three times. If n=0.5, then I need to replicate it only one time... so n needs to be round up.

2)  Create a new variable called t, where the sum of t for each id must equal to n.

3)  Create another new variable called accumulated.t

Here how the output looks like:

```
id  n   t   accumulated.t
1   2.63    1   1
1   2.63    1   2
1   2.63    0.63    2.63
2   1.5 1   1
2   1.5 0.5 1.5
3   0.5 0.5 0.5
4   3.5 1   1
4   3.5 1   2
4   3.5 1   3
4   3.5 0.5 3.5
5   4   1   1
5   4   1   2
5   4   1   3
5   4   1   4
```

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking someone to code this for you which isn't how Stack Overflow works. Which part exactly are you having trouble with? Did you write any code at all? Where exactly did it fail?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688717/round-up-from-5-in-r) might help, but I'm voting to close until you show some effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `ceiling` of 'n' column and use that to expand the rows of 'mydata' (`rep(1:nrow(mydata), ceiling(mydata$n))`)

Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydata1)`), grouped by 'id' column, we replicate (`rep`) 1 with `times` specified as the `trunc` of the first value of 'n' (`rep(1, trunc(n[1]))`).  Take the difference between the unique value of 'n' per group and the `sum` of 'tmp' (`n[1]-sum(tmp)`). If the difference is greater than 0, we concatenate 'tmp' and 'tmp2' (`c(tmp, tmp2)`) or if it is '0', we take only 'tmp'.  This can be placed in a `list` to create the two columns 't' and the cumulative sum of 'tmp3 (`cumsum(tmp3)`).

```
 library(data.table)
 mydata1 <- mydata[rep(1:nrow(mydata),ceiling(mydata$n)),]
 setDT(mydata1)[, c('t', 'taccum') := {
         tmp <- rep(1, trunc(n[1]))
         tmp2 <- n[1]-sum(tmp)
         tmp3= if(tmp2==0) tmp else c(tmp, tmp2)
         list(tmp3, cumsum(tmp3)) },
                                  by = id]
 mydata1
#  id    n    t taccum
# 1:  1 2.63 1.00   1.00
# 2:  1 2.63 1.00   2.00
# 3:  1 2.63 0.63   2.63
# 4:  2 1.50 1.00   1.00
# 5:  2 1.50 0.50   1.50
# 6:  3 0.50 0.50   0.50
# 7:  4 3.50 1.00   1.00
# 8:  4 3.50 1.00   2.00
# 9:  4 3.50 1.00   3.00
#10:  4 3.50 0.50   3.50
#11:  5 4.00 1.00   1.00
#12:  5 4.00 1.00   2.00
#13:  5 4.00 1.00   3.00
#14:  5 4.00 1.00   4.00
```

Comment: @user9292 No problem.  In the future, it is better to show what you tried to make it more interesting for others.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that utilizes base R.

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), n=c(2.63, 1.5, 0.5, 3.5, 4))
mynewdata <- data.frame(id = rep(x = mydata$id,times = ceiling(x = mydata$n)),
                        n = mydata$n[match(x = rep(x = mydata$id,ceiling(mydata$n)),table = mydata$id)],
                        t = rep(x = mydata$n / ceiling(mydata$n),times = ceiling(mydata$n)))
mynewdata$t.accum <- unlist(x = by(data = mynewdata$t,INDICES = mynewdata$id,FUN = cumsum))
```

We start by creating a `data.frame` with three columns, `id`, `n`, and `t`. `id` is calculated using `rep` and `ceiling` to repeat the ID variable the number of appropriate times. `n` is obtained by using `match` to look up the right value in `mydata$n`. `t` is obtained by obtaining the ratio of `n` and `ceiling` of `n`, and then repeating it the appropriate amount of times (in this case, `ceiling` of `n` again.

Then, we use `cumsum` to get the cumulative sum, called using `by` to allow by-group processing for each group of IDs. You could probably use `tapply()` here as well.