# R way of rounding when last decimal is 5

Tags: r, rounding

How does R round numbers with the `round()` function?
For example:

```
round(0.345, 2)
# [1] 0.34
```

I would expect 0.35.

```
round(0.3455, 3)
# [1] 0.346
```

This is what's expected.

Comment: this is in the documentation `?round`: `Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’. Therefore round(0.5) is 0 and round(-1.5) is -2.`

Comment: see also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845236/round-but-5-should-be-floored

Comment: @rawr, post as answer (I don't see an exact dupe) ?

Answer (score 0):

One hack to that function I've used before to get what you expect out of it...  If the number has 5 decimal accuracy, multiply by your desired # of decimals to round off (I.e. *1000), call as.integer() on the result, then multiply by 0.001. A simple function follows this psuedo code:

Make your own function with an input for the # of decimals desired.  Multiply the input value by 10^(# decimals input).  Do an as.integer() on this value.  Now multiply by 10^(-# decimals input).  Return this value.