# R: What is wrong with rounding?

Tags: r, rounding

> round(c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5))

Output: 0 2 2 4 4 6 6

I do not see a problem, when X.5 rounds to X or to X+1 (I could accept that as a matter of definition).
I can not understand when X.5 rounds to X+1 but some Y.5 rounds to Y. For example, round(1.5)=round(2.5)=2 ?!
Thanks a lot for your help in understaning!

Comment: This is documented on the help page  `?round`.  The relevant part is `Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’.`  See also [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39913257/4752675)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Interesting way of rounding :/ ...