# How can I consistently round up .5 decimal values ​in R?

Tags: r, floating-point

The help of `round` states that **‘go to the even digit’** is used for rounding.

How can I have a consistent rounding mechanism?

---

For example:

This rounds up.

```
round(1.5, 0)
```

> 2

This rounds down.

```
round(4.5, 0)
```

> 4

**In both cases I want it to round up.**

But I also want 1,4 to round down and 1,7 to round up.

Comment: `floor(x + 0.5)`, with some corner cases

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688717/round-up-from-5)

Comment: Before implementing this, you should think about whether you *really* need to always round up. There are good reasons that `round` works the way it does - to avoid bias.  Have alook at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Answer (score 0):

There is the functions `floor()` and `ceiling()`

```
floor(1.5)
```

> 1

```
ceiling(1.5)
```

> 2

Comment: But I also want 1,4 to round down and 1,7 to round up.