# Error in either `/` or round functions from base R

Tags: r, data.table

I have been trying to make a contribution to the `data.table` package by adding the `round` function to the `ITime` class, when i came across a rather odd discrepancy produced by the `round` function. Behind the scenes, an object of class `ITime` is just an integer vector with pretty formatting, and thus `unclass(object)` provides an integer vector.

Rounding this integer vector to the nearest minute can thus be done like this:

```
x <- as.ITime(seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 07:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 07:10:00"), "30 sec"))

round(unclass(x) / 60L) * 60L
# or 
round(as.integer(x) / 60L) * 60L
```

Here is where the problem comes...

When I do this operation, I would expect any instance of `unclass(x) / 60` that ends with .5 to be rounded up. However, that is not the case!

[image]

I have tried the example on both Windows and Mac on two different computers with the same result. Does anyone have an idea as to why this would happen?

** FYI I know that this particular problem can be solved differently: `unclass(x) %/% 60L`. But my interest is in why the `round` function does not work as expected.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12688717/3576984

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you! Very helpful description of the problem :-)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thank you! Awesome to see that there is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?round`:

> ```
> ‘round’ rounds the values in its first argument to the specified
>  number of decimal places (default 0).  See ‘Details’ about “round
>  to even” when rounding off a 5.
> ```

[...]

> ```
> Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard (see also
>  ‘IEEE 754’) is expected to be used, ‘_go to the even digit_’.
>  Therefore ‘round(0.5)’ is ‘0’ and ‘round(-1.5)’ is ‘-2’.  However,
>  this is dependent on OS services and on representation error
>  (since e.g. ‘0.15’ is not represented exactly, the rounding rule
>  applies to the represented number and not to the printed number,
>  and so ‘round(0.15, 1)’ could be either ‘0.1’ or ‘0.2’).
> ```