# R round() rules for .5

Tags: r

Does rounding rules for .5 applies also for .05, .005 etc? I couldn't figure out why rounding for 45.445 and 73.445 differ.

```
> round(45.445,2)
[1] 45.45
> round(73.445,2)
[1] 73.44
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12688717/680068

Comment: @zx8754 jakob's question was about custom round rules. I'm trying to understand a specifc case.

Comment: This answer from the linked post might explain the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39913257/680068 Try this example: `round(seq(1:10) + 0.445, 2)`

Comment: @zx8754 that resulted in .44 when integers are 2 and 3, and .45 when else. I don't get the logic in that. Couldn't find it in that answer aswell. Did you figure that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *double* numbers are not represented exactly and `round` uses the represented number.

```
sprintf("%.20f", 45.445)
#[1] "45.44500000000000028422"
sprintf("%.20f", 73.445)
#[1] "73.44499999999999317879"
```

Comment: Oh, i get it now! Since 5 isn't the last number or it's not followed by zeroes, R doesn't apply the round to even rule. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Round does not get `45.445` it gets `sprintf("%a", 45.445)` `0x1.6b8f5c28f5c29p+5` or `45.44500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125`.