# Using floor and ceiling on different values of one variable in R

Tags: r, rounding, stata, floor, ceil

I would like to format a variable in R, using `round`, `floor` or `ceiling`. However, I would like to sometimes use `floor`, sometimes `ceiling` for different values of the same variable. Is that possible?

My dataframe is `data` and the variable I want to format is `var`. These are its values (with frequencies):

```
Value    |      Freq.
---------|-----------
1        |       1504
1.333333 |        397
1.5      |          9
1.666667 |        612
2        |       2096
2.333333 |       1057
2.5      |         18
2.666667 |       1270
3        |       2913
3.333333 |       1487
3.5      |         35
3.666667 |       1374
4        |       2007
4.333333 |        779
4.5      |         16
4.666667 |        522
5        |       1913
NaN      |        553
```

My desired result is a variable `var2` that looks like this:

```
Value |      Freq.
------|-----------
1     |       1910
2     |       3783
3     |       5670
4     |       4195
5     |       2451     
NaN   |        553
```

So, 1.5 and 2.5 are adjusted downward (`floor`), but 3.5 and 4.5 are adjusted upward (`ceiling`). The other values are rounded the usual way.

My attempt is this, but it does not work yet:

```
data$var2 <- format(round(data$var, 1))
if (data$var2 == 1.7||2.7||3.5||3.7||4.5||4.7) {
  data$var2 <- format(ceiling(data$var2))
} else {
  data$var2 <- format(floor(data$var2))
}
```

I know that there are probably several mistakes in my attempt and would appreciate any help.

PS: What I'm actually looking for is an equivalent for Stata's function `egen` `cut`. With that it is very easy to achieve the desired result:

```
egen var2 = cut(var), at(1, 1.6, 2.6, 3.5, 4.4, 5.1)
recode var2 (1 = 1) (1.6 = 2) (2.6 = 3) (3.5 = 4) (4.4 = 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package for this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(var2 = case_when(var %in% c(1.5, 2.5) ~ floor(var),
                          var %in% c(3.5, 4.5) ~ ceiling(var),
                          TRUE ~ round(var)))
```

This returns the following `data.frame`:

```
        var var2
1  1.000000    1
2  1.333333    1
3  1.500000    1
4  1.666667    2
5  2.000000    2
6  2.333333    2
7  2.500000    2
8  2.666667    3
9  3.000000    3
10 3.333333    3
11 3.500000    4
12 3.666667    4
13 4.000000    4
14 4.333333    4
15 4.500000    5
16 4.666667    5
17 5.000000    5
18      NaN  NaN
```

You can customize the conditions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this answer is wrong!

I am not sure this is the desired outcome. It seems to me that you want to round to the nearest integer, except for the values 1.5 and 2.5. A decimal of 0.5 is rounded up by default (**this is not true!** [Round up from .5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688717/round-up-from-5)).

```
custom.rund <- function(x){
  if(x %in% c(1.5, 2.5)){
    floor(x)
  } else {
    round(x)
  }
}

sapply( c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2, 4.6), custom.rund )
[1] 1 2 4 2 5
```

Comment: I used `sapply(data$var2, custom.rund)` and it returned `Error in round(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Comment: as the errors says, most likely ````data$var2```` is not numeric. You can check that using `class(data$var2)`

Comment: Try to input `4.5` to your function. The output is `4`, not `5`.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `ifelse(x %in% c(1.5, 2.5), floor(x), round(x))`, but more time-consuming. Just an advice, no offense.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks a lot! Always willing to learn. I didnt not know about the IEC 60559 standard.