# Commercial rounding in R - i.e. always round up from .5?

Tags: r

Here `round()` behaves as expected:

```r
round(3.5)
[1] 4
```

However [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzPmjvi6rr0) was surprising to me:

```r
round(2.5)
[1] 2
```

#### Question

In times when we want ***everything*** ending in `.5` to be rounded **up**, what's best practice in R to achieve that?

#### Note

Ideally the solution should also cater for rounding beyond the first decimal place e.g. the following should return `0.2`:

```r
round(0.15, 1)
[1] 0.1
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you understand *why* `round` behaves the way it does, and why its way of rounding is generally superior?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do but only after learning of the difference in norms. I believe it's simply a norm in some places to round 0.5 to the nearest *even* number (irrespective of whether that may be higher or lower than the input), whereas in other places it's the norm to always round 0.5 up without exception.

Comment: @user2974951 I hadn't either until 25 minutes ago :)

Comment: @user2974951 Have a look at the [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). In a nutshell, other rounding methods introduce a systematic bias. By contrast, round-half-towards-even doesn’t: a distribution of random numbers has the same mean before and after rounding with this method.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm beginning to question everything my 3rd grade math teacher taught me!

Comment: @stevec Tell me about it! I almost had an existential crisis when I learned this.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, right?

Comment: @BenBolker I rewrote the title for visibility, mostly because I googled just now and couldn’t find it and a *lot* of other similar but different questions come up on google. I guess TL;DR the answer has probably been provided many times before, but probably to different variations on the question. FYI I requested a native implemtation in base R: https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/121

Comment: `janitor::round_half_up()` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/vignettes/janitor.html#directionally-consistent-rounding-behavior-with-round_half_up

Answer (score 1):

After googling for 'commercial rounding in r', [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12688836/5783745) answer comes up, which can be adapted to have a default value of 0 decimal places like so:

```r
round2 = function(x, decimal_places = 0) {
  posneg = sign(x)
  z = abs(x)*10^decimal_places
  z = z + 0.5 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
  z = trunc(z)
  z = z/10^decimal_places
  z*posneg
}
```

Examples:

```
round2(3.5)
[1] 4

round2(2.5)
[1] 3

round2(0.15, decimal_places = 1)
[1] 0.2
```