# Summary R function: rounding values

Tags: r, rounding, summary

I want to know if there is any possibility to change the round method of the summary r function for values like that:

```
> mean(c(1, 12,28,30, 34,25,35, 40))
[1] 25.625

> summary(c(1, 12,28,30, 34,25,35, 40))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00   21.75   29.00   25.62   34.25   40.00
```

In the summary function, I want the mean to be rounded as **25.63** and not 25.62

have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `round2` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12688836/3962914) :

```
round2 = function(x, n) {
  posneg = sign(x)
  z = abs(x)*10^n
  z = z + 0.5 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
  z = trunc(z)
  z = z/10^n
  z*posneg
}
x <- c(1, 12,28,30, 34,25,35, 40)

round(mean(x), 2)
#[1] 25.62

round2(mean(x), 2)
#[1] 25.63

round(summary(x), 2)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   1.00   21.75   29.00   25.62   34.25   40.00 

round2(summary(x), 2)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   1.00   21.75   29.00   25.63   34.25   40.00
```