# Round up from 0.5 AND round up from -0.5 in R

Tags: r, rounding

This question does not duplicate [Round up from 0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688717/round-up-from-5). I am looking for different behavior. I want -0.5 to round up to 0, and 0.5 to round up to 1. This behavior needs to work consistently for all numbers with decimal values of -0.5 or 0.5.

Here is the result I want:

```
c(-0.7, -0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5)
[1] -1 0 0 0 1
```

With **round** I get this:

```
> round(c(-0.7, -0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5))
[1] -1  0  0  0  0
```

With **ceiling** I get this:

```
> ceiling(c(-0.7, -0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5))
[1] 0 0 0 1 1
```

janitor::round_half_up() doesn't seem to work on negative numbers.

```
> round_half_up(c(-0.7, -0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5))
[1] -1 -1  0  0  1
```

`floor()` obviously doesn't do what I'm looking for, and neither does the `round2()` function that is sometimes suggested for other questions about rounding.

Thank you!

Comment: You can write a custom function specifying two conditions for those two specific values and leave the rest to `ceiling`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR this is only a sample dataset to indicate the behavior I want. There are many other values in the dataset and I need consistent output for all values.

Comment: `trunc` would get you most of the way there, but it doesn't round, per se. It just chops off the decimals.

Comment: Can you just add a small number to all data? like `a=c(-0.7, -0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5); round(a+0.001)`. Choose a small enough number for your dataset.

Comment: @Bing that might work. I'll have to try it on my full dataset and run some checks.

Comment: Actually, my answer is already in "Round up from 0.5".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to get everything to round 0.5 up is to use `floor(x + 0.5)`:

```r
x <- c(-0.7, -0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.5)
floor(x + 0.5)
#> [1] -1  0  0  0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>